# Why my swiper buttons are not visible and not working in reactjs code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, swiper.js

Here is the code of the ROW slider using swiper and 2nd code is the buttons but still button are not showing up on screen at all,and not working as well

i can see the buttons in inspect element , but i cant see in on screen, and when i click it , it doesnt work. and also i can see the default navigation buttons of swiper. i want my buttons to come and swiper's default navigations button not to come

Row.js code

```
//some code

import { Swiper, SwiperSlide, useSwiper } from 'swiper/react';
import { Navigation } from 'swiper/modules';
import '../../node_modules/swiper/swiper-bundle.css';
import SwiperButton from './SwiperButton';

function Row({ title, fetchUrl }) {
  const [anime, setAnime] = useState([]);
  const swiper = useSwiper();

 //some more code
enter code here
  return (
    <div className='row'>
      <h1>{title}</h1>
      <div className='row__posters' data-aos='slide-right' data-aos-once='true'>
        <Swiper
          modules={[Navigation]}
          slidesPerView={7}
          navigation
          onSwiper={(swiper) => console.log(swiper)}
          onSlideChange={() => console.log('slide change')}
        >
          {anime.map(
            (anime) =>
              anime.animeImg && (
                <SwiperSlide>
                  <Link to={`/info/${anime.animeId}`}>
                    <div className='row__poster-container'>
                      <img
                        className={`row__poster`}
                        key={anime.id}
                        src={anime.animeImg}
                      ></img>
                      {
                        <p className='overlay-text'>
                          {truncate(`${anime.animeTitle}`, 20)}
                        </p>
                      }
                    </div>
                  </Link>
                </SwiperSlide>
              )
          )}
          <SwiperButton />
        </Swiper>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Row;
```

and here is the code for SwiperButton.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { useSwiper } from 'swiper/react';

export default function SwiperButton() {
  const swiper = useSwiper();
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => swiper.slidePrev()}>Prev</button>
      <button onClick={() => swiper.slideNext()}>Next</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: does the console show any errors?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how but when u change classname to swiper-button-next , it is working

```
<div className='swiper-button-next'>
  <button onClick={() => swiper.slidePrev()}>Prev</button>
  {console.log('Buttons')}
  <button onClick={() => swiper.slideNext()}>Next</button>
</div>
```